# Ajax Request Fails on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a problem with my AJAX request here. I am displaying data through a foreach loop creating delete buttons for each entry. The first time I click on one of these button the entry is being deleted properly, but then the second click on the next element fails.

```
<?php foreach ($notes as $note): ?>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
               $("<?php echo '#NoteDeleteButton' . $note['Note']['id']>").bind("click", function () {
                    $.ajax({async: true,
                           dataType: "html", success: function (data) {
                           $("#NoteUpdateSection").html(data);
                    }, type: "POST", url: "<?php if($this->base != '') { echo '' . $this->base; } ?>\/notes\/delete\/<?php echo $note['Note']['id'] ?>\/<?php echo $current_controller ?>\/<?php echo $current_id ?>"});
                    return false;
               });
       });
</script>

...

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In my browsers console I get this error after clicking the delete button the first time:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError:
Unexpected identifier   jquery.min.js?1406620464:2
(anonymous function)    jquery.min.js?1406620464:2
n.extend.globalEval     jquery.min.js?1406620464:2
n.fn.extend.domManip    jquery.min.js?1406620464:3
n.fn.extend.append      jquery.min.js?1406620464:3
(anonymous function)    jquery.min.js?1406620464:3
n.access                jquery.min.js?1406620464:3
n.fn.extend.html        jquery.min.js?1406620464:3
$.ajax.success          71:13184
j                       jquery.min.js?1406620464:2
k.fireWith              jquery.min.js?1406620464:2
x                       jquery.min.js?1406620464:4
b                       jquery.min.js?1406620464:4
```

Do you have any ideas how to deal with this? I appreciate your help! Many thanks!!

Comment: I think it's perhaps that you are replacing the buttons with dynamically added content.  Have a look at delegated events http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: You mentioned there are already error after first click. seems it's coming from html() function. What is the data returned from ajax call ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake: it was an incomplete Ajax request above this code.